# WordPress: save `get_template_part()` to variable

Tags: wordpress, templates

In short, all I need is to make my WordPress do this

```
$var = get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
```

but, `get_template_part()` does not return HTML, it prints it. 
I need this HTML stored in `$var` - do you have any ideas how to do it?

Comment: would you print it later? I mean the `$var`.

Answer (score 114):

This isn't what `get_template_part` was for, get_template_part essentially behaves like PHP's require function. [Justin Tadlock writes a lot more about this here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/17/how-to-load-files-within-wordpress-themes) and also talks about a Wordpress function that might be more useful to you - `locate_template`.

Alternatively, if you did want to hack this functionality using get_template_part, you could use template buffering:

```
function load_template_part($template_name, $part_name=null) {
    ob_start();
    get_template_part($template_name, $part_name);
    $var = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $var;
}
```

Comment: when i put this in my theme i only get bacon and not the file's contents.... :   echo "bacon " . load_template_part('registration-form.php');

Comment: I'm not sure where Atomicus says that they want the literal unprocessed PHP, get_template_part acts as an include rather than a file-content-getter.

Comment: should comment back to say that you're right this totally works, i was feeding the wrong info to the function (adding .php).  <facepalm> though i would set $part_name=NULL by default so you can just called load_template_part('content-aside')

Comment: @helgatheviking - excellent point, edited as per your suggestion

Comment: This is the reason why wordpress sucks, very ugly solution and very error sensitive.

Comment: @Erwinus That's not why WP sucks ;) as stated in the answer - it is a hack, if for some reason you didn't want to use the intended method for this, `locate_template`.

Comment: @Simon Scarfe: Yes it really sucks because of the old separated header, content and footer structure and you cannot change it without hacking wordpress. I need to change something in the header based on the content but it is impossible without hacking the wordpress template system. Header is generated before content. locate_template doesn't make any sense either because it is an include. Why using the overhead of a wordpress function to include something. Yes there are ways to change the header based on some content but with overhead or very ugly.

Comment: Late in to the conversation, my bad. To be fair, it really acts more like an include than a require; it would still work if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score 17):

I'm not loving Output Buffering, though +1 for even thinking of that as an option!

I think Helga was on to something, but you need to still respect the child_themes and the theme path, so use `locate_template()` instead (also as Simon suggested).

This works nicely, and can even be used inside a filter or (in my case) shortcode function (I wanted my shortcode to output the content within a template-style file, to separate the display layer from the logic layer).

```
return file_get_contents(locate_template("template-file-name.php")); // don't forget the .php!
```

Comment: I tried that, but that didnt execute the template page, is there a way to execute it and return the output string?

Comment: You need to use output buffering in that case as per @SimonScarfe's answer.

Answer (score 2):

what about?

```
$file = file_get_contents(STYLESHEETPATH . '/template-part.php'); 
return $file;
```

i'm sure there is a better way, but that seems to work for me.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to create a shortcode with the HTML return, the example below works for me:

```
function funcao_produtos_filtro_ead() { 

    $html = "";

    ob_start();
    
    // LOOP DE PRODUTOS
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => '-1'
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );

        endwhile;
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return '<div class="woocommerce">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    
  }

  add_shortcode('produtos_filtro_ead', 'funcao_produtos_filtro_ead');
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
ob_start(); 
get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );
$var = ob_get_clean();
```