# How to separate WordPress posts loop in to two columns?

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I need to separate WordPress posts loop in to 2 columns , left and right.

Currently I am doing this with 2 separate loops but would like to make it with one if possible.

```
<div class="left-side">
    <?php 
        $row_start = 1; 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            if( $row_start % 2  != 0) {// odd
                get_template_part( 'blog','item');
            }
            ++$row_start; 
        endwhile;
    ?>
</div>
<div class="right-side">
    <?php  
      $row_start = 1; 
       while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        if( $row_start % 2 == 0) {// even
            get_template_part( 'blog','item');
        }
        ++$row_start; 
        endwhile;
    ?>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That can't be done, as long as you are outputting the content directly. You'd need to assemble the content inside two string variables first, and then output those after your loop.

Comment: @CBroe any idea how I am about to do that by WP coding standards ?

Comment: I am not aware of any built-in function to get the result of a template call into a variable, but it can be done using output buffering, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5817726/wordpress-save-get-template-part-to-variable

Comment: Why would you sacrifice very readable and easy to understand code for the mess of spaghetti you will end up with?

Comment: @Luke, I thought there is better , cleaner way that the one I have now.

Answer (score 2):

Move the loops into a separate template files.

Create two files in your themes directory, one named `posts-odd.php` and the other named `posts-even.php` and add the post loops respectively, i.e:

`posts-odd.php`:

```
<?php 
    $row_start = 1; 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
        if( $row_start % 2  != 0) {// odd
            get_template_part( 'blog','item');
        }
        ++$row_start; 
    endwhile;
?>
```

`posts-even.php`:

```
<?php  
  $row_start = 1; 
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
    if( $row_start % 2 == 0) {// even
        get_template_part( 'blog','item');
    }
    ++$row_start; 
    endwhile;
?>
```

In your main template you can now use `get_template_part` function to include the partial template into your main template:

```
<div class="left-side">
    <?php get_template_part('posts', 'odd') ?>
</div>
<div class="right-side">
    <?php get_template_part('posts', 'even') ?>
</div>
```

If you're displaying the odd and even posts in various places this will give you the benefit of only having to define the loop templates once.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/

Comment: now I missed that completely! thnx for thinking about it. it does not place them in to one , but it looks better than  2 loops dangling and can be reused in shortcodes.

Answer (score 1):

Not easy but possible.

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$column = array();
$column[1] = $column[2] = '';

if (have_posts()) :
    while (have_posts()) :
        the_post();

        $i++;

        $column[$i] .= '<div class="'.esc_attr(implode(' ', get_post_class())) .'">';

            $column[$i] .= '<div class="post_inner">
                            '.get_the_content().'
                            </div>
                        </div>';

        $i = ($i==2) ? 0 : $i;

    endwhile; ?>

    <div id="grid_posts">
        <div class="span6"><?php echo $column[1]?></div>
        <div class="span6"><?php echo $column[2]?></div>
    </div>

<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php esc_html_e('No posts were found. Sorry!', 'mytheme'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Basically you create columns array and put your contents in there in two keys (1 and 2), and every 2 posts you put in one column, and keep increasing the counter to 2 and resetting it once it gets to 2. So you keep filling the array with posts - first to key 1 and then to key 2 and so on.

Then you just output those two into 2 columns (`span6` in my case).

Hope this helps.